# How should I store a reference variable for continued iteration in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am looking for the best way to store a variable, `$i.Name` or  `$i.LastWriteTime`, so that I can continue loading Folder names into my .exe without duplication.

**Possibly something like:**

```
$LastFolderProcessed = "Stored LastWriteTime from last processing"
if ($i.LastWriteTime -gt $LastFolderProcessed } | `
Continue....
```

I wrote a script, launched from Task Scheduler, to complete the following steps:

1.) Check original directory and copy new items(Folders) into processing
  directory.

2.) Loop through processing directory and find each item

3.) Assign each item to a variable $i.Name

4.) Define CMD and Args. Run(&).

**Script**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Force

cpi C:\Apps\AutoTest\Analysis\2016\*  C:\Apps\AutoTest\Loading -Recurse

foreach($i in Get-ChildItem C:\localApps\AutomationTest\Loading)
{

    if ($i.PSisContainer) {$i.Name}

    $CMD = 'C:\Program Files\Analysis\LoadProgram.exe'
    $arg1 = "-database:Data Source=MSSQLSERVER"
    $arg2 = "-directory:C:\Apps\AutomationTesting\Loading\$i"
    $arg3 = "-config:C:\Program Files\Analysis\Configs\loadconfig.xml"

   & $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3
}

$i.LastWriteTime
```

The script runs my .exe [with Args] and will load the `$i.name` variable with each folder name it finds. If there are 5 folder names in the directory then it will run the .exe 5 times for each iteration.

The Script will run daily.

I am looking for a good way to store a reference variable so that, in say 2 days, if the script launches and finds 3 new folder names it will just process the new Folders.

This is where I was thinking my best bet might be using something like `$i.LastWriteTime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far the easiest way is to use `Export-Clixml` and `Import-Clixml`. These cmdlets serialize objects into an XML file, and the reverse.

So for example if you wanted to store the whole file list:

```
$list = Get-ChildItem #...

$list | Export-Clixml -Path C:\my\path\MyFiles.xml
```

The reload it, it's much the same:

```
$oldList = Import-Clixml -Path C:\my\path\MyFiles.xml
```

Comment: Then all you'd need to do is check current write times against previous write times with what you imported.

Comment: @briantist  This is great. Worked really well. Here is a good reference link I used as well.  [Import-Clixml](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176873.aspx)

Comment: @ChrisKuperstein  I am looking up the compare process. Would this be something like `Compare-Object -ref $oldList -diff $list` `if ($list.LastWriteTime -gt $oldList.LastWriteTime } | `
Continue....(Load lastest folder names into process)

Comment: @Twdeveloper I would ask in another question for that :)