# How do I compare variable properties in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am looking to do a comparison on two variables `$list` and `$oldList` that I generated using `Import/Export-Clixml`.

Here is the my reference question that I had previously asked. It contains more details if needed.

[How should I store a reference variable for continued iteration in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36363768/how-should-i-store-a-reference-variable-for-continued-iteration-in-powershell)

Since, I tested the following script successfully:

```
$list = Get-ChildItem C:\localApps\AutomationTest\Loading | where {$_.PSIsContainer}
$list | Export-Clixml C:\LocalApps\AutomationTest\Loading\foldernames.xml
$oldList = Import-Clixml C:\LocalApps\AutomationTest\Loading\foldernames.xml
$oldList
```

My goal is to compare the `$list.LastWriteTime` to the `$oldList.LastWriteTime` and obtain any new directory names that were added to the list since the "oldList" was generated. These new Directory names will then be processed and added to the "oldList"...and so on.

Was thinking maybe something like the following could work?

```
Compare-Object -ref $oldList -diff $list 
if ($list.LastWriteTime -gt $oldList.LastWriteTime} 
"Continue....(Load lastest folder names into process)"
```

Comment: So if a folder in `$list` is newer than it's counterpart in `$oldList` and add it to `$oldlist`? So if the folder is new it should be added as well

Comment: Why not just overwrite the entire list then with the current one that is up to date? You need to keep the old ones that no longer exist? I think i'm a little lost as to what your end game is.

Comment: @Matt I am checking a directory for new Folder Names. I will then load the new folder name into my script variable to be processed by my .exe. This script run everyday and checks for new folders to load. I just want to make sure it doesn't process duplicate names. So I have decided to add folder names that have already been processed into an oldList. I will then check my Directory for new folder names and only process them if they more current then the last name in OldList.

Comment: I get that but what does last write time have to do with it had me wondering

Comment: Oh. I was looking to only process folder names that were -gt lastwriteTime in the oldList. Figured that was a good way to go. If not, then this is why I am on StackOverflow. To learn the best way.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Compare-Object` is what you are asking for. Just need to be sure you are doing the correct post processing. If you are just looking for changes that exist in the `$list` then use the correct side indicator when filtering with `Where-Object`.

```
Compare-Object $oldList $list | Where-Object{$_.Sideindicator -eq "=>"} | Select-Object -expandProperty InputObject
```

That will just return the Directory.Info objects that correspond to folders that didn't exist in the `$oldList`. Capturing the output from that command is what you are doing to need for your other processing.

After that then just take `$list` and output that to the location that `$oldList` came from. Not much to it other than that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of doing date time checking against the old XML for each folder item that existed previously. It will skip any that weren't in the old list.

Hopefully this gives you a good starting point.

```
$oldList = Import-Clixml #etc

function Check-Against ([PsObject]$oldList, [string]$path){

    $currentItems = Get-ChildItem $path | ? {$_.PSIsContainer}

    foreach ($oldItem in $oldList){

        $currentItem = $currentItems | ? Name -like ($oldItem.Name)

        if ($currentItem -ne $null){
            $oldWriteTime = $oldItem.LastWriteTime
            $val = $currentItem.LastWriteTime.CompareTo($oldWriteTime)

            if ($val -gt 0){
                # Folder has been changed since then
                # Do your stuff here
            }

            if ($val -eq 0){
                # Folder has not changed
                # Do your stuff here
            }

            if ($val -lt 0){
                # Somehow the folder went back in time or was restored
                # Do your stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
```